# Variables looking strange in NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, cocos2d-iphone, nslog

I'm pretty new to iphone app development, and so I'm starting off using the Cocos2d framework instead of entirely objective c from scratch, because it has lowered the learning curve some and I'm finding it much easier. I'm attempting to do some of the tutorials off the Cocos2d website, but, being human rather than a sheep, have decided to try some stuff that wasn't in the tutorial.

So, here's the relevant code from the tutorial:

```
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];
    [cocosGuy stopAllActions];
    [cocosGuy runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp( location.x + 32, location.y + 32)]];
```

This works as expected, the cocos guy moves to where I touch my ipod with a one second delay and a 32 pixel offset. So now, I wanted to get some textual feedback as well about where I was tapping the screen. I tried to use NSLog to display some information about the `location` of the touch:

```
 NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"x=%d y=%d", location.x, location.y]);
```

Xcode kindly informs me: `Format not a string literal and no format arguments`. Unless I'm entirely mistaken, `@"text"` is a string literal in objective C and the two location variables are the format arguments.

When run, the console displays something like:

```
2011-06-20 19:54:22.765 Lesson1[315:707] x=0 y=1078640640
2011-06-20 19:54:23.887 Lesson1[315:707] x=0 y=1080631296
2011-06-20 19:54:24.576 Lesson1[315:707] x=0 y=1080242176
```

when I touch the ipod screen at three random places. x never seems to change and y is always a massive integer.

What is wrong with my code, and being new to the world of iphone development, objective c, and cocos2d, how can I go about trying to better debug this myself in the future?

Please note that this is literally my second day of experimenting with all of this, so forgive me if this is an incredibly obvious or stupid question.

Comment: The compiler is preventing you from creating a classic security hole;  If your string happened to have an inadvertent escape sequence sometimes created, then you'd have a nice denial-of-service attack on your hands (at best).

Comment: @bbum Denial of service to what? An ipod? And it didn't prevent me from compiling, it just threw a warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `x, y` members of `CGPoint` are `float`s, not `int`s, hence you should use `%f` instead of `%d`.

Also, `NSLog()` is able to do formatting itself. Try:

```
NSLog(@"x=%f y=%f", location.x, location.y);
```

instead. Note that in the code above the first parameter to `NSLog()`:

```
@"x=%f y=%f"
```

is a string literal, whilst in your code the first parameter is not literal:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"x=%d y=%d", location.x, location.y]
```

Comment: That fixed it. And brings on another two small questions: How do I cast to an int? And, how could I convert that NSString object to a string literal?

Comment: @Cyc If you need to cast to an `int`, use `(int)location.x` (and then `%d` in the format string would be fine). And you cannot convert that particular string to a literal string because it depends on the values of `location.x` and `location.y`, and those are only known (and can vary) at runtime. Note that `@"x=%f y=%f"`, being a format string, can be literal because it is not concerned about the actual values that will be formatted.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you’re using the wrong string format specifiers.

`%d` is for an `int`, but the `x` and `y` attributes of a `CGPoint` struct are actually `CGFloat` (which is defined as either a `float` or `double`, depending on 32 or 64 bit)

You can see Apple’s list of format specifiers here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

It says CGFloats should use `%f` or `%g` instead.

To make `+stringWithFormat:` interpret the values correctly, your format string should look like `@"x=%f y=%f"`

Another tip – NSLog() actually has formatting built in, so you can just use

```
NSLog(@"x=%f y=%f", location.x, location.y);
```

instead of also `[NSString stringWithFormat:…`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the warning is that `NSLog` expects its first argument to be a string literal, and you are passing it an object that you've just created.  Also, I'm pretty sure `location.x` and `location.y` will be floating point numbers, not integers.  Try using `%f` instead of `%d`.  At any rate, you should use `NSLog` to format the string instead, like so:

```
NSLog(@"x=%f y=%f", location.x, location.y);
```